# initial connections refused - connection warm up?

Tags: tcp, arp

I've got two firewalled VMs connected to the same vLAN but I see RST/ACK responses on initial connection attempts in a while only to succeed on immediate following attempts, like some sort of cache needs to be initiated of peers. Wondering what might cause such, arp cache maybe?

Initial connection attempt:

```
15:04:56.786105 IP <redacted>.185.60362 > <redacted>.154.ldap: Flags [S], seq 3402 134510, win 26880, options [mss 8960,sackOK,TS val 429607411 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:04:56.786377 IP <redacted>.154.ldap > <redacted>.185.60362: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3402134511, win 0, length 0
```

Following successful attempt:

```
15:05:11.363088 IP <redacted>.154.ldap > <redacted>.185.60378: Flags [S.], seq 310 2507846, ack 3252771331, win 26844, options [mss 8960,sackOK,TS val 538726974 ecr 429621988,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:05:11.363120 IP <redacted>.185.60378 > <redacted>.154.ldap: Flags [.], ack 1, win 210, options [nop,nop,TS val 429621988 ecr 538726974], length 0
```

On destination VM I'm seeing relative frequent arp requests like these whenever there's communication otherwise not, like server wants to ensure client peers is still there (on the same HN maybe though mac-addr should change during live migration, switches might need to know this quickly):

```
18:56:08.164227 ARP, Request who-has <redacted>.184 tell <redacted>.154, length 28
18:56:08.164687 ARP, Reply <redacted>.184 is-at 62:38:31:33:39:39, length 46
```

It appears as expected that I've got no duplicate IP addresses assigned, so why would peers keep sending relative many arp req.s?

```
[root@dcs2 ~]# arping  -DI eth1 <redacted>.184
ARPING <redacted>.184 from 0.0.0.0 eth1
Unicast reply from <redacted>.184 [62:38:31:33:39:39]  1.122ms
Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 1 response(s)

#n1:/> arping  -DI eth1 <redacted>.154
ARPING <redacted>.154 from 0.0.0.0 eth1
Unicast reply from <redacted>.154 [6E:FF:D6:F0:78:C6]  1.107ms
Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 1 response(s)
```

It could appear to be arp cache warm-up issue if I do an arping first there's no initial issue:

```
#n2:/> arping -I eth1 -f dcs4.<redacted>; telnet dcs4.<redacted> 389
ARPING <redacted>.156 from <redacted>.185 eth1
Unicast reply from <redacted>.156 [92:B9:56:CE:03:E6]  1.150ms
Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 1 response(s)
Trying <redacted>.156...
Connected to dcs4.<redacted>.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

But how to avoid the initial issue in general as it affects our applications?

Comment: I'm think a bit more information about your VM host and guests and what sort of networking you have setup (bridge,NAT, something else) would help..

Comment: VMs are running CentOS 6.8 in a Proxmox PVE 4.2 cluster, where HypervisorNodes runs openvswitch 2.5 to interconnect/brigde VMs through 2x 10Gbs bonded NICs. HNs runs iptables on VM's tapped IFs by added a std linux brigde in serial on the tapped IF plugged into openvswitch brigde. Let me know if more info is required!

Comment: All NWs are ipv4 only. VMs are running kernel 4.6.1 but have seen this also on previous kernel 4.x. HNs are running kernel 4.4.8. Both VMs and HNs have default arp timeout of 60 sec: #n2:/> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_stale_time
60

Comment: Nice summation! So, when you say new connections, are they from outside your network, on the same LAN segment or some other situation (other VMs for example)?

Comment: Inside my NWs, between two VMs on the same vLAN, but across their firewalled IFs, like: VM1<->std.br<->OVS1<--interHN-->OVS2<->std.br<->VM2

Comment: Seems to work fine between two VMs without fw-brigdes or just with fw-bridge on destination VM

Comment: It's like the FW is lacking short term memory almost..

Comment: I'm thinking the openvswitch is the culprit, but I hesitate to make any more pronunciations, since I'm pretty much at my knowledge threshold in this case :)

Comment: Or the FW only has very short term memory :) Ok maybe I'll take it to the OVS mailing list. Me too, hence this posting :/ but thanks for reading so far. For now I did a work-around, it's only nagging a bit though.

Comment: Just to throw another voice into the mix, for server A to physically send a SYN packet to server B, it has to know the destination MAC address, so it would appear that layer 2 is working correctly. The RST immediately after SYN is interesting and I would be interested to know whether it is actually server B that is sending this RST. If so, it would appear to be a Layer 4 issue.